# Reporting Services Expression error (decimal) on different Timezone

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

I have a classic "work on my machine" error.
I have Reporting Services Expression, that will give me % on each row. On my machine works fine (TimeZone / Cultural Settings / Languale -> Poland), and on serwer it don't work (TimeZone / Cultural Settings / Language - England).

```
=FormatNumber(Round((Fields!Wartosc_Pln.Value * 100 / CDec(Parameters!SummaryCurrentInwest.Value)) ,2),2) + " %"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try something like this: `=FORMAT(Fields!Wartosc_Pln.Value * 100 / CDec(Parameters!SummaryCurrentInwest.Value), "P")`

Comment: Still "works on my machine" :/

Comment: My parameter is "string". Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: The problem was the parameter type: string. After change to decimal (in .rdlc) now problem don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was data type of parameter in report (.rdlc file). After change from string to float, now it works on both servers.